# How to fix this .htaccess rewrite rule error?

Tags: .htaccess, joomla

My website is not working anymore and I have error messages in my error log file. This happened suddenly after attempting to load files such as videos and images.

Here is an extract from my error log file:

```
RewriteRule: cannot compile regular expression '^([0-9]+)\\/([^\\d\\/]+)([0-9]+).**\\/[0-9]+,[0-9]+\\)\\).*\\/*![0-9]+.**\\/\\)``\\)``\\)\\)$'
/homez.133/schweitzo/www/.htaccess: RewriteRule: cannot compile regular expression '^([0-9]+)\\/([^\\d\\/]+)([0-9]+).**\\/[0-9]+,[0-9]+\\)\\).*\\/*![0-9]+.**\\/\\)``\\)``\\)\\)$'
```

And here is the content of my `.htaccess` file:

```
SetEnv PHP_VER 5_3 SetEnv MAGIC_QUOTES 0
##
# @package      Joomla
# @copyright    Copyright (C) 2005 - 2014 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license      GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
##
##
# READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE!
#
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that dissallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
##
## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above. Options +FollowSymLinks
## Mod_rewrite in use. RewriteEngine On
## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL. RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL. RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL. RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL. RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#
## End - Custom redirects
##
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##
# RewriteBase /
# RewriteRule ^/?([\w+\s-]+)$ ?x=$1 [QSA,L] ?$2$1=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L] RewriteRule
^([0-9]+)\/([^\d\/]+)([0-9]+).**\/[0-9]+,[0-9]+\)\).*\/*![0-9]+.**\/\)``\)``\)\)$
?$2$1=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
# RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/([^\d\/]+)([0-9]+)-[0-9]+\/.*..*$ ?$2$1=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
# RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the request is for something within the component folder,
# or for the site root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
# requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$
[NC]
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `.htaccess` file is broken. Your `RewriteRule` is commented out but the following regex is on a newline. You can choose to comment all part of the RewriteRule or uncomment it depending on your needs.

Uncommented:

```
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/?([\w+\s-]+)$ ?x=$1 [QSA,L] ?$2$1=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/([^\d\/]+)([0-9]+).**\/[0-9]+,[0-9]+\)\).*\/*![0-9]+.**\/\)``\)``\)\)$ ?$2$1=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/([^\d\/]+)([0-9]+)-[0-9]+\/.*..*$ ?$2$1=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Or commented:

```
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##
# RewriteBase /
# RewriteRule ^/?([\w+\s-]+)$ ?x=$1 [QSA,L] ?$2$1=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
# RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/([^\d\/]+)([0-9]+).**\/[0-9]+,[0-9]+\)\).*\/*![0-9]+.**\/\)``\)``\)\)$ ?$2$1=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
# RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/([^\d\/]+)([0-9]+)-[0-9]+\/.*..*$ ?$2$1=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
# RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Correct version :

```
SetEnv PHP_VER 5_3 SetEnv MAGIC_QUOTES 0
##
# @package      Joomla
# @copyright    Copyright (C) 2005 - 2014 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license      GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
##
##
# READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE!
#
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that dissallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
##
## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above. Options +FollowSymLinks
## Mod_rewrite in use. RewriteEngine On
## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#
## End - Custom redirects
##
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/?([\w+\s-]+)$ ?x=$1 [QSA,L] ?$2$1=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L] RewriteRule
^([0-9]+)\/([^\d\/]+)([0-9]+).**\/[0-9]+,[0-9]+\)\).*\/*![0-9]+.**\/\)``\)``\)\)$
?$2$1=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/([^\d\/]+)([0-9]+)-[0-9]+\/.*..*$ ?$2$1=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the request is for something within the component folder,
# or for the site root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
# requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
```

Comment: I tried this with Rewriterule commented it gave me another error message But at least I can access Joomla Administrator
With the Line Uncommented it gives the same error message 500

NEW error messageWarning: require(/home/schweitzo/www/wp-blog-header.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/schweitzo/www/index.php on line 24

Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/home/schweitzo/www/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5.3/lib/php') in /home/schweitzo/www/index.php on line 24

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have still troubles. I have tried this with Rewriterule commented it gave me another error message about WP (strange I use Joomla) But at least I could access Joomla Administrator
With the Line Uncommented it gives the same error message 500
So the web site is still Down. Is it possible that .htaccess was hacked ? what can I do with .htaccess to fix that issue ? 
NEW error messageWarning: require(/home/schweitzo/www/wp-blog-header.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/schweitzo/www/index.php on line 24

Comment: you can try the "Correct version", I've updated it. I've added a `joomla` tag in your question as it seems to be a specific `Joomla` `.htaccess` problem, other users with Joomla knowledge will help you.